# Long and Short press on a UIBUTTON

Tags: ios, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, long-press

I need to implement long and short press for one button. how to go about with it. I implemented long press using longPressGestureRecognizer .. now i dont know how to do the same for short press.. its like for short press it has to load view1 and for long view2.

thank you.

Comment: A short press is. the `TouchUp inside` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By short press I assume you mean a tap on the button. If you are using a nib you can connect the button action event for touch or touch up inside to an IBAction. If not you can use addTarget:action:forControlEvents detailed here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

If you decide not to use a button or not to use the UIControl methods, you can attach a UITapGestureRecognizer to the same view with a different target action.